# What do you like most of all in school?

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-structure

Is it correct to say that, using "most of all" or we have some better choices to ask such question?

> What do you like **most of all** in school/at work...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "*most of all*" or "*best of all*" if you want someone to respond with just *one thing* that they like most/best.

If you ask what people like best (or most) about something, they may list a number of things. A group of things can be described as "the best", for example, an album of songs may be titled "the best of [artist]" because all of the songs on that album are among the artist's best work. By adding "...of all" you are soliciting just one response - the best of the best.

Another way to do this would be to use the definite article and ask:

> What is *the best thing* about school?

Comment: As I understood from your text, "What do you like most/best in school?", "What do you like most/best about school?" also are idiomatic? Am I right?

Comment: @Sergey Yes - "about" is more open, it could invite any aspect of school life. "At" school seems a little more specific, most people would take that to mean a subject or some aspect of educational life at school.